# ElasticSearch NEST MultiGet with Source Filtering

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I am attempting to make use of multi get to return a collection of strongly typed objects with source filtering and although I have been able to create the result I want with the JSON API for ElasticSearch, I am not sure how to translate it into the NEST 1.0 API.

This is the query I am trying to produce; it works correctly:

```
GET index/thing/_mget 
{
    "docs" : [
        {
            "_id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000030",
            "_source": ["id", "name"]
        },
        {
            "_id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000321",
            "_source": ["id", "name"]
        }
        /* ....  */
    ]
}
```

This is what I've been toying with but it does not actually filter the sources; instead, it's returning the full object:

```
client.MultiGet(s => s
    .GetMany<Thing>(ids)
    .SourceEnabled("id", "name"))
```

Any help would be appreciated. Also, it would be preferable to use a signature for the  `SourceEnabled()` call which is expression based (type safe), if one exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug.  I just opened [issue #849](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues/849) on GitHub to address this.

In the meantime, specifying fields serves a similar purpose and might be a workaround for you:

```
var result = client.MultiGet(s => s
    .GetMany<Thing>(ids, (d, i) => d.Fields("id", "name"))
);

var fieldSelection = result.GetFieldSelection<Person>(1);
var fields = fieldSelection.FieldValues<string>("name");
```